# Mathematica Conditions for Functions

Tags: conditional-statements, wolfram-mathematica

So in Mathematica, if I have a function lambda1 that is defined below, how do I create a condition that if `lambda1 < 1e-300`, then `lambda1 = 1` and if `lambda1 > 1e-300`, it equals its true value?

`x={1,5,9}` and mx and sx are defined later in the code when I run a Monte Carlo integration.

```
 f[x_,mx_,sx_] := (1/(sx*Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Exp[-((x-mx)^2)/(2*(sx^2))]
 lambda1[xx1_,mx_,sx_,xx2_,xx3_,gamma1_] := 1/((f[x1,mx,sx]*f[x2,mx,sx]*f[x3,mx,sx]))
```

Comment: I want to fix lambda1 = 1 if the result of lambda < 1e-300

Comment: You have a comment on how to do `if` statements with mathematica here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87308/multiple-lines-in-an-if-statement